# PHP. Check if an array (multidimensional? numeric?) has some values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to check if in my array that come from database (SQLSERVER, so odbc) I have a some values.

I have this code:

```
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "SELECT NumNation, NumPlayers FROM table1";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);

while($rows = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
$myArray[] = $rows['NumNation']."=>".$rows['NumPlayers']; //this
```

Or I can have also this:

```
$myArray[] = $rows; //or this
} // close while
echo ("<br>".implode(",<br>",$myArray).".<br>");
```

Then I have some other code for select from another database tables and then I want to check if in my array (from the first table) I have this data or not.

I wrote this for example:

```
$NumNation = '123'
$Players   = '456'

if (in_array($NumNation."=>".$NumPlayers, $myArray)) continue;
```

and the continue with my code for save and something else.

But the check doesn't work.

Why?

If I var_dump myArray I have this:

```
array(363) { [0]=> string(31) " =>2000-12-31 00:00:00" [1]=> string(31) " =>2000-12-31 00:00:00" [2]=> string(31) " =>2000-12-31 00:00:00" [3]=> string(36) " 15=>2001-02-28 00:00:00" [4]=> string(36) " 18=>2001-02-28 00:00:00" [5]=> string(36) " 18=>2001-02-28 00:00:00" [6]=> string(36) " 14=>2001-02-15 00:00:00" [7]=> string(36) " 12=>2001-02-10 00:00:00" ....so on until......[347]=> string(31) " 4 =>2013-07-23 00:00:00" [348]=> string(31) " 5 =>2013-07-23 00:00:00" [349]=> string(2) "=>" [350]=> string(36) " 011013=>2013-10-01 00:00:00" [351]=> string(36) " 011013=>2013-10-01 00:00:00" [352]=> string(36) " 011213=>2013-12-01 00:00:00" [353]=> string(36) " 011213=>2013-12-01 00:00:00" [354]=> string(36) " 0112131=>2013-12-01 00:00:00" [355]=> string(36) " 0112131=>2013-12-01 00:00:00" [356]=> string(36) " 100=>2014-11-30 00:00:00" [357]=> string(31) " 1 =>2014-12-02 00:00:00" [358]=> string(31) " 1 =>2014-12-02 00:00:00" [359]=> string(31) " 1 =>2014-12-02 00:00:00" [360]=> string(26) "00032=>2014-02-12 00:00:00" [361]=> string(26) "00032=>2014-02-12 00:00:00" [362]=> string(26) "00017=>2014-02-12 00:00:00" }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Have you var_dumped the $myArray? Your second example doesn't really look relavent to what your in_array is looking for.

Comment: The while loop in the first snippet has no closing brace.

Comment: Also if I have in the array the couple (Numnation => 123 and Players => 456) the check say me the couple isn't.

Comment: Yes I know Palec, is an example, for understanding logic.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, I var_dumped myArray. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "SELECT NumNation, NumPlayers FROM table1";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
$myArray = array();
while($rows = odbc_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $myArray[$rows['NumNation']] = $rows['NumPlayers'];
}

$NumNation = 123;
$NumPlayers = 456;
ksort($myArray);
foreach($myArray as $key=>$val) {
     if($key == $NumNation && $val == $NumPlayers) {
         continue;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think the `foreach` is a bit heavy. Do not you think?

Comment: Do you know any better ways ?